# how to get jQuery autocomplete extraParam to evaluate current value

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am having the same issue as described here - http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2009/09/08/jquery-autocomplete-extraparams-and-checkboxes/

In short, when using autocomplete, I am getting the initial value of the variable for the area select box.  Unlike the example above, however, the value of the parameter actually becomes the text of the function, rather than the evaluated value of the function.

So instead of getting "option2", for example, I am getting "function(){return$('#area :selected').val();}'

Here is my code:

```
$().ready(function() {$("#course").autocomplete("autoCompleteMain.php", {
        width: 360,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false,
        extraParams: {
            dateran : $('#dateran').val(),
            area1 : function (){
                return $('#area :selected').val();
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do correctly, you will need to either evaluate the function:

```
area1 : (function (){
           return $('#area :selected').val();
        })()
```

..or simply use the current value of the selected area

```
area1 : $('#area :selected').val()
```

Comment: This fixed the issue of the code being treated as text.  Unfortunately, now the evaluation is always the initial value once again.  One step forward and one step back.

Comment: Yes—the option is only set when the autoComplete plugin is loaded up. If you're trying to change it later, your best bet might be to listen for a `blur` event on `$('#course')` and reset the value accordingly.

Comment: Understood.  Is there a way to access the original parameter value (to  update it) or do I need to use a separate variable in my code instead of the parameter?

Comment: `autoComplete` may provide an interface for accessing it, but it will probably be easier to assign your own variable and use it as needed (my vote :^).

Comment: The autoComplete gave me what I needed.  Using this in combination with an event capture permits update of the autocomplete object parameter.

Comment: sorry, more specifically, the .setOptions permitted update of the object parameter.